# Django 1.8: add user to Modelform in views: not null constraint failed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I know there are a lot of similar questions here, but none of them seem to be working with my view in Django 1.8 with a ModelForm.

I have a user profile form that works as long as I have each required field in the template context, but I only want each logged in user to fill out their own form.

I'm doing something wrong here, and I'm not sure what the problem is. Can someone correct me? I've spent hours looking at other posts and trying various suggestions from SO.  I'm getting "NOT NULL constraint failed: camp_userprofile.user_id"

Here's my models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User) 
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 20)  
    needs_camp_bike = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    diet_lifestyle = models.CharField(max_length = 200, choices=What_are_you, null=True, blank=True)
    meal_restrictions = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank= True)
    other_restrictions = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    arrival_day =  models.IntegerField(choices=Days)
    departure_day = models.IntegerField(choices=Days)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' %(
            self.user,  self.picture, self.city, 
            self.needs_camp_bike, 
            self.diet_lifestyle, self.meal_restrictions, self.other_restrictions, 
            self.arrival_day, self.departure_day
            )
```

My forms.py
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    Fish = "Fish"
    Mammal = "Mammal"
    Vegetarian = "Vegetarian"
    Omnivore = "Omnivore"
    Onions = "Onions"
    Cucumber = "Cucumber"
    Peppers = "Peppers"
    Gluten_free = "Gluten_free"
    Vegan = "Vegan"
    Shellfish = "Shellfish"
    Olives = "Olives"
    Pork = "Pork"
    Soy = "Soy"
    Dairy = "Dairy"
    Cilantro = "Cilantro"
    Quinoa = "Quinoa"
    Nightshades = "Nightshades"
    Nuts = "Nuts"
    Pescaterian = "Pescaterian"

    Restrictions = (
      (Mammal, "Mammal"),
      (Onions, "Onions"),
      (Cilantro, "Cilantro"),
      (Soy, "Soy"),
      (Dairy, "Dairy"),
      (Quinoa, "Quinoa"),
      (Pork, "Pork"),
      (Olives, "Olives"),
      (Dairy, "Dairy"),
      (Peppers, "Peppers"),
      (Cucumber, "Cucumber"),
      (Nightshades, "Nightshades"),
      (Nuts, "Nuts")
    )

    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('picture', 'city', 
            'needs_camp_bike', 'diet_lifestyle',
            'other_restrictions', 'arrival_day', 
            'departure_day', 'meal_restrictions')

    widgets = {
        'meal_restrictions': forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=Restrictions),
    }
```

and my views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user =request.user.username
            form.save(commit=True)
        else:
            print(messages.error(request, "Error"))
    return render(request, "profile.html", RequestContext(request, {'form': form, 'profile': profile,}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do `form.user = request.user.username`, because `form.user` won't add the user to the form. You should capture the object that `form.save(commit=false)` returns, then assign the user to that object and save it.

Also you cannot assign a user field with `username`, `username` is only a string not `User` object. You should do this instead:

```
if form.is_valid():
    userprofile = form.save(commit=False)
    userprofile.user = request.user
    userprofile.save()
```

Comment: The code you give here is the correct answer, but the diagnosis of the problem is incomplete. The issue, apart from the assigning of username, is that OP is ignoring the object returned by `form.save()`, assigning the user to the *form*, then saving the form again, rather than assigning the user to the object itself.